# Opportunity related to product

Tags: visualforce

I have a request to display all related opportunity records for a particular product2 using a visualforce page on thé product2 object

Comment: Could you share what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, please see our [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) section and check how to form questions here.