# Display opportunies related to product

Tags: visualforce

I have à request to display opportunities related to product object by using visualforce page on Product2

Comment: So are you getting any problem?  you just need to make a query like...  select id, opportunity.name from opportunitylineitem where product2id ='<Id of currebt product>>'

Comment: Please avoid creating duplicate questions: [Opportunity related to product](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268347/opportunity-related-to-product).

Comment: Please post under only one user account. Do not post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to use Visualforce Page to show Opportunities related to a product. You already have a related list called Opportunities on Product record Page layout which shows you the Opportunity related to current product record.

[image]

Comment: I have not this related liste on my Product page layout!!